# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{m}(n+i)$ is divisible by $(m+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

Given a sum
$$s = \sum_{i=0}^{m}(n+i)=(n+0)+(n+1)+...+(n+m)$$
with $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, how could I prove that $s$ is divisible by $m+1$ when $m$ is even?

I do know that
$$s = (m+1)n + \sum_{i=0}^{m}i$$
and since $(m+1)n\over(m+1)$$=n$ I just have to prove that the sum of all natural numbers from $0$ to $m$ is divisible by $(m+1)$. How could I do that?

Comment: $0+1+2+3=3\frac{3+1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that \begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^m i = \sum_{i=1}^m i
 = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}\end{align}
But $m=2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ (since $m$ is even), so $$\sum_{i=0}^m i= \frac{2k(m+1)}{2} = k(m+1).$$
That is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^mi$ is divisible by  $(m+1)$ when $m$ is even.

So now, putting everything together with what you already have, \begin{align}s=(m+1)n + k(m+1) = kn(m+1),\end{align} i.e. $s$ is divisible by $(m+1)$ when $m$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the sum of $m+1$ consecutive  terms of an *arithmetic sequence*:
$$a_n+a_{n+1}+\dots+a_{n+m}=(m+1)\dfrac{a_n+a_{n+m}}2.$$